# How can I keep track of changes to files by specific programs?

Tags: files

In Ubuntu, is it possible to keep track of all programs that are used to modify one file? For example, if I had a file called `sampleText.txt`, would it be possible to generate a list of every edit that had been made to that file, along with each program that had edited it?

Comment: I think that it's a great idea for a utility, I'll keep watching for an answer :)

Comment: I had asked about this in a limited way [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/70744/15760) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2131182). My query was limited to text files and didn't extend to keeping track of the programs that created or edited them.